# iOS 32 vs 64 bit apps

Tags: ios

So with Apple forcing new apps to support 64 bit, support for iPhone 5 will be completely dropped.

I do know that iPhone 5 can't support 64 bit apps however right now all apps run fine on iPhone 5.

As a developer, I just write my app and I never check a box that converts it to 64. Do all new apps support both 32 and 64 by default? Do I need to take extra steps to support 32 bit?

I'm pretty confused. Sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: Yes - every app has 32 and 64 runtimes inside so it can run on both architectures.

Comment: So the whole thing is for apps written in very old Xcode versions pre 64 bit support that don't support 64 bit?
And basically all new apps will support both 32 and 64 with no extra work from developers? @Makalele

Comment: You won't be able to send app to the AppStore with very old Xcode versions anyway. It's about devices - iPhone 5 has 32bit architecture. They dropped 32bit so in the future they may remove 32bit runtimes to reduce app size. For now it's an excuse for abandoning old devices.

Comment: Ah so right now apps compile into 32 and 64 but in the future they will eventually remove the 32 all together and kill the iPhone 5 for good? @Makalele

Comment: I think so, but I won't happen in near future.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. Makes sense now. You should have replied to the question so I can mark it as solved :P @Makalele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - every app has 32 and 64 runtimes inside so it can run on both architectures.

You won't be able to send app to the AppStore with very old Xcode versions anyway. It's about devices - iPhone 5 has 32bit architecture. They dropped 32bit so in the future they may remove 32bit runtimes to reduce app size. For now it's an excuse for abandoning old devices.